# Reducing RAM consumption of Python dict

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, dictionary

I have a python script that process several files of some gigabytes. With the following code I show below, I store some data into a list, which is stored into a dictionary `snp_dict`. The RAM consumption is huge. Looking at my code, could you suggest some ways to reduce RAM consumption, if any?

```
def extractAF(files_vcf):
    z=0
    snp_dict=dict()
    for infile_name in sorted(files_vcf):
        print '      * ' + infile_name
        ###single files
        vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(infile_name, 'r'))
        for record in vcf_reader:
            snp_position='_'.join([record.CHROM, str(record.POS)])
            ref_F = float(record.INFO['DP4'][0])
            ref_R = float(record.INFO['DP4'][1])
            alt_F = float(record.INFO['DP4'][2])
            alt_R = float(record.INFO['DP4'][3])
            AF = (alt_F+alt_R)/(alt_F+alt_R+ref_F+ref_R)
            if not snp_position in snp_dict:
                snp_dict[snp_position]=list((0) for _ in range(len(files_vcf)))
            snp_dict[snp_position][z] = round(AF, 3) #record.INFO['DP4']
        z+=1
    return snp_dict
```

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264874/python-reducing-memory-usage-of-dictionary

Comment: use a database ... store records there rather than in memory ...

Comment: Try the `shelve` standard library module.

Comment: `if not snp_position in snp_dict` looks fishy, are you intending to do `if snp_position not in snp_dict`?

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing, you are probably better off using another data structure.  A pandas `DataFrame` would work well in your situation.

The simplest solution would be to use an existing library, rather than writing your own parser.  [vcfnp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vcfnp/) can read vcf files into a format that is easily convertible to a pandas `DataFrame`.  Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
    def extractAF(files_vcf):
    dfs = []
    for fname in sorted(files_vcf):
        vars = vcfnp.variants(fname, fields=['CHROM', 'POS', 'DP4'])
        snp_pos = np.char.add(np.char.add(vars.CHROM, '_'), record.POS.astype('S'))
        dp4 = vars.DP4.astype('float')
        AF = dp4[2:].sum(axis=0)/dp4.sum(axis=0)
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(AF, index=snp_pos, columns=[fname]).T)
    return pd.concat(dfs).fillna(0.0)
```

If you absolutely must use PyVCF, it will be slower, but hopefully this will at least be faster than your existing implementation, and should produce the same result as the above code:

```
def extractAF(files_vcf):
    files_vcf = sorted(files_vcf)
    dfs = []
    for fname in files_vcf:
        print '      * ' + fname
        vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(fname, 'r'))
        vars = ((rec.CHROM, rec.POS) + tuple(rec.INFO['DP4']) for rec in vcf_reader)
        df = pd.DataFrame(vars, columns=['CHROMS', 'POS', 'ref_F', 'ref_R', 'alt_F', 'alt_R'])
        df['snp_position'] = df['CHROMS'] + '_' + df['POS'].astype('S')
        df_alt = df.loc[:, ('alt_F', 'alt_R')]
        df_dp4 = df.loc[:, ('alt_F', 'alt_R', 'ref_F', 'ref_R')]
        df[fname] = df_alt.sum(axis=1)/df_dp4.sum(axis=1)
        df = df.set_index('snp_position', drop=True).loc[:, fname:fname].T
        dfs.append(df)
    return pd.concat(dfs).fillna(0.0)
```

Now lets say you wanted to read a particular `snp_position`, say contained in a variable `snp_pos`, that may or may not be there (from your comment), you wouldn't actually have to change anything:

```
all_vcf = extractAF(files_vcf)
if snp_pos in all_vcf:
     linea_di_AF = all_vcf[snp_pos]
```

The result will be slightly different, though.  It will be a pandas `Series`, which is like an array but can also be accessed like a dictionary:

```
all_vcf = extractAF(files_vcf)
if snp_pos in all_vcf:
     linea_di_AF = all_vcf[snp_pos]
     f_di_AF = linea_di_AF[files_vcf[0]]
```

This allows you to access a particular file/snp_pos pair directly:

```
all_vcf = extractAF(files_vcf)
if snp_pos in all_vcf:
     f_di_AF = linea_di_AF[snp_pos][files_vcf[0]]
```

Or, better yet:

```
all_vcf = extractAF(files_vcf)
if snp_pos in all_vcf:
     f_di_AF = linea_di_AF.loc[files_vcf[0], snp_pos]
```

Or you can get all `snp_pos` values for a given file:

```
all_vcf = extractAF(files_vcf)
fpos = linea_di_AF.loc[fname]
```

Comment: `if not snp_position in snp_dict:
                snp_dict[snp_position]=list((0) for _ in range(len(files_vcf)))` is not arbitrary... I need 0s or 0.000s (float)

Comment: Fixed.  The last line takes care of that for you.

Comment: how could I change `        if snp_pos in all_vcf:
          linea_di_AF=all_vcf[snp_pos]` in order to read the `DataFrame`?

Comment: I have added an explanation on how to do this

Comment: Is `vcf_reader` a sequence (you can loop over it multiple times) or is it an iterator (you can only loop over it once)?  And is, for example, `record.INFO['DP4'][0]` some sort of numeric type or a string?  These can be used to improve performance.

Comment: I have updated the code again.  I included an alternative using a different python package, as well as a faster version of my original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I finally adopted the following implementation with `MySQL`:

```
for infile_name in sorted(files_vcf):
    print infile_name
    ###single files
    vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(infile_name, 'r'))
    for record in vcf_reader:
        snp_position='_'.join([record.CHROM, str(record.POS)])
        ref_F = float(record.INFO['DP4'][0])
        ref_R = float(record.INFO['DP4'][1])
        alt_F = float(record.INFO['DP4'][2])
        alt_R = float(record.INFO['DP4'][3])
        AF = (alt_F+alt_R)/(alt_F+alt_R+ref_F+ref_R)
        if not snp_position in snp_dict:
            sql_insert_table = "INSERT INTO snps VALUES ('" + snp_position + "'," + ",".join(list(('0') for _ in range(len(files_vcf)))) + ")"
            cursor = db1.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql_insert_table)
            db1.commit()
            snp_dict.append(snp_position)
        sql_update = "UPDATE snps SET " + str(z) + "g=" + str(AF) + " WHERE snp_pos='" + snp_position + "'";
        cursor = db1.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_update)
        db1.commit()
    z+=1
return snp_dict
```