# Memory error when processing files in Python

Tags: python

I intend to read a file, which is about 500MB in total, into a dict according to the key in each line. The code snippet is as follows:

```
f2 = open("ENST-NM-chr-name.txt", "r")   # small amount
lines = [l.strip() for l in f2.readlines() if l.strip()]
sample = dict([(l.split("\t")[2].strip("\""), l) for l in lines])    ## convert [(1,2), (3,4)] to {1:2, 3:4}
```

When running on a machine with memory of 4GB, the python complains Memory Error. If I change the evaluation expression of `sample` variable to `[l for l in lines]`, it works fine.

At first, I thought it was due to the `split` method that was consuming lots of memory, so I adjust my code to this:

```
def find_nth(haystack, needle, n):
    start = haystack.find(needle)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start+len(needle))
        n -= 1
    return start

...

sample = dict([(l[find_nth(l, "\t", 4):].strip(), l) for l in lines])
```

But it turns out the same.

A new discovery is that it will run normally without OOM provided I remove the `dict()` conversion regardless of the code logic.

Could anyone give me some idea on this problem?

Comment: Somewhere on this site is a question about how much memory a `dict` takes, and it's much more than you would expect.

Comment: Could you give out the specific URL link related to what you've mentioned? Thanks. @MarkRansom

Comment: If I could remember it, I would have done so already. Sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264874/python-reducing-memory-usage-of-dictionary

Comment: Also, are you reading tab-separated values?

Comment: Yep, tab-separated, any optimized suggestions? @minitech

Comment: @Judking: Yep – [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) is very flexible.

Comment: @Judking Do you really need a dictionary? The fact that you are assigning 1 to all the keys make me wonder if you actually don't need a `set` instead (maybe not).

Answer (score 2):

You’re creates a list containing every line, which will continue to exist until `lines` goes out of scope, then creating another big list of entirely different strings based off of it, then a `dict` off of that before it can go out of memory. Just build the `dict` in one step.

```
with open("ENST-NM-chr-name.txt") as f:
    sample = {}

    for l in f:
        l = l.strip()

        if l:
            sample[l.split("\t")[2].strip('"')] = l
```

You can achieve about the same effect by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, but it feels nicer (to me) not to `strip` twice.

Comment: I removed the explicit `r` mode, because it is the default.

Comment: I agree, about not repeating `strip`. Another option is to do `map(str.strip, f)` (in Python 3), or `itertools.imap(…)` (in Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

What if you turn your list into a generator, and your dict into a lovely **dictionary comprehension**:

```
f2 = open("ENST-NM-chr-name.txt", "r")   # small amount
lines = (l.strip() for l in f2 if l.strip())
sample = {line.split('\t')[2].strip('\"'): line for line in lines}
```

Line 2 above was mistakenly `lines = (l.strip() for l in f2.readlines() if l.strip())`

Do a generator and a dict comprehension perhaps (somehow) alleviate the memory requirements?

Comment: This does not solve the (likely) problem of reading the whole file into memory (which is an unnecessary waste, in any case). minitech's answer avoids this.

Comment: Doesn't using a generator to read lines do exactly that? Since it doesn't build a list of lines in memory?

Comment: You are not using a generator, with your `f2.readlines()`: this puts the whole file in memory (since it builds a *list* with all the lines). `readlines()` can be avoided, most of the time. Even if you avoided it here by doing `for l in f2`, (where f2 is an iterator) you would still be storing all the lines in your `lines`. Again, minitech's answer is the way to go (smallest memory footprint possible).

Comment: @EOL: `lines = (l.strip() for l in f2 if l.strip())` would make it a lazily-evaluated generator. (Note parentheses instead of square brackets.)

Comment: Oops, I meant to remove `readlines()`... and do `l in f2`, as per minitech's comment.

Comment: @minitech Good point, I read too fast and had missed the parentheses instead of brackets. Python could be even more explicit than it is already, by forcing `iter()` to be used. :)